# how to merge boot partition with other partition separated by a grub2 partition

Tags: partitioning, grub2, gparted

I have a machine where due to its history the grub partition sits between two large ext4 partitions, all seen in the picture below. I would like to merge the two partitions which currently sandwich the grub partition (as seen below, one of them is already empty and ready to be re-claimed). So that I'll effectively have one big continuous ext4 partition.

How would I most elegantly and safely move the grub partition and merge the two large partitions which currently surround it?

[image]

I found that GParted doesn't offer a way to move the grub partition, at least not when the system is live, and later I found that using GParted from a live USB stick won't allow moving the grub partition either, even though there is a very large unallocated partition (see in the picture again). So I am wondering how to safely and possibly also simply accomplish this in order to better utilize my drive.

---

### Some additional technical details which hopefully do not matter

In case this ties in, this machine should always boot from one partition, all other detectable OS partitions other than its `/dev/sda5` are either invalid or completely obsolete. I'd like to move the grub2 partition so that I then can make `/dev/sda5`, my only boot partition, larger.

And in case it matters, `/dev/sda2` is still shown as a boot option in my grub menu even though I've already un-allocated that partition altogether (it's that empty partition right before the grub2 partition in the picture).

Thanks!!

Comment: We don't know if you use BIOS-boot (for that this partition is needed) or UEFI-boot (for that the first partition `sda1` is needed). If you use UEFI-boot, the BIOS-boot-partition is not needed and could be simply deleted. If you really use BIOS-boot and move the BIOS-boot-partition you will have to reinstall Grub (boot-loader).

Comment: Would UEFI simply boot into the Ubuntu partition without any necessary setup if grub is removed?

Comment: You can confirm how you boot: Check UEFI boot mode
`[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo EFI || echo Legacy` Also if fstab mounts the ESP - efi system partition. There are two versions of grub. One for BIOS grub-pc that uses the bios_grub on gpt drives and one for 64 bit PC UEFI boot grub-efi-amd64.

Comment: This question is still open, and additional detail has been added

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live [USB disk](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview). Using gparted you should then be able to simply move the grub partition. Just make sure the disk isn't mounted. And of course: Make sure you have a backup before doing that.

Comment: Will I be able to then also merge the free space that would become contiguous to my ext4 parition after moving the grub partition like so?

Comment: By live USB disk I assume a USB stick where Ubuntu can be booted from

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't pose any problem. Just right-click the grub partition, select "change size/move" and move it to the left. Then you can do the same thing to the ext4 partition. Move it to the left and then adjust the size to include the unallocated space.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can use an Ubuntu live USB stick. Check out this tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Awesome. I thought but wanted some advice before going that route. Hope this answer helps other people as well in the future!

Comment: Sure! :) Good luck and don't forget to back up any important data just in case.

Comment: Actually from live USB the grub partition can't be moved using Gparted. The option is grayed out.

Comment: Can you make sure that no partition is still mounted? Right click the partitions in gparted and click "unmount".

Comment: Already unmounted. Alas, ordered a new drive instead.